# iOS file preview

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, ios4, ios6

I want a file preview in application.
File is from web server (I have url of file.)
May can be any type. (image/audio/video/doc etc)

I want previewer like Finder previewer in Mac (by pressing space to any file in mac)

Comment: You have to write it yourself

Comment: I want 1 billion dollar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5837993/1106035

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method, IMO, would be to simply use a UIWebView.

`[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileUrl]];`

Where `fileUrl` is an `NSURL` pointing to the file's URL (remote or local).  From my experience, UIWebViews are extremely capable of opening many different file types efficiently.

Comment: The problem with UIWebView is that it leaks memory really bad specially with images.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html). You can look at the tutorial here for an example of how to use it:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/previewing-and-opening-documents-with-uidocumentinteractioncontroller/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with UIWebView is that it has memory leaks that will cause your app to crash if you persistently preview images, you can check the behavior through instruments. I think the best way of doing so if you don't care about encryption is to use Quick Look Previewer. If you care about encryption, you can use UIImageView